# Whats Intent lifecycle?

Tags: android, android-intent

Say i have started activity ***A*** with new Intent(context,class) ***i*** thats has sensitive data in it, when is this intent gets destroyed? in particular, in what cases among the following would getIntent() in Activity ***A***'s code return the exact same intent ***i***?

1. Press on the activity's task on android's task manager
2. App icon was clicked and the activity was recreated and brought to front

Ive tried it with my app, iand i get weird results... normally it doesnt get the same intent, but sometimes it seem that it does, so i am not sure whats going on, anyway If ***i*** can be returned from any of the upper options how to avoid it?

I think a glance on lifecycle of an Intent would be helpfull if any1 know of any documentation regarding this...

Comment: as long as A is in memory, it will keep intent values passed to it

Answer (score 1):

> Say i have started activity A with new Intent(context,class) i that's has sensitive data in it, when is this intent gets destroyed?

as long as there's object/class that holds reference to your `Intent` object - it will not be garbage collected.   the Activity (Activity A) holds reference to the intent that started it, so as long as `Activity` A object is not garbage collected - then `i` also won't be garbage collected.

important comment: onDestroy() activity callback and class distractor are to different things!!!

> in what cases among the following would getIntent() in Activity A's code return the exact same intent i?

assuming you are not calling `setIntent()` explicitly:

> 1) Press on the activity's task on android's task manager:

if the activity was previously stopped in reaction to back button navigation  or someone called `finish()` explicitly on it, then the activity passed on the `onDestroy()` callback. in that case - pressing on the "application" from the recent tasks manager would re-created the activity with a new intent from scratch, and thus - `getIntent()` would bring this new intent that don't contain your extras or other overloads.

otherwise (the activity was sent to background via home button, or other activity started on top of it) :  when you'll launch it back from the recent task - it will be intent object with the original extras you passed it before...

> 2) App icon was clicked and the activity was recreated and brought to
>   front

basically the same cases I mentioned in (1) apply to (2) , **but** basically it depends on two more things:

- the [intent flags](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#IntentFlagsForTasks) that the specific launcher you are using is overloading on the intent it creates when it launch your activity.
- the [launch mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) and activity flags you overloaded on the intent that you used to start your own activity.

assuming you are not using any of the above, and you are using normal good functional launcher application - the behavior would be exactly as I explained in (1)